# Is there a way to fix the zip creation for a Lambda function using the Terraform data "archive_file"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to deploy an AWS lambda function using Terraform and the archive_file data resource.

It succeeds the first time, but then it fails indefinitely because it is not able to create the zip again:

```
"╷

│ Error: reading ZIP file (modules/my_module/.1a0b8615d1fd5b70a7f6/lambda.zip): open modules/my_module/.1a0b8615d1fd5b70a7f6/lambda.zip: no such file or directory

│

│ with module.my_module.aws_lambda_function.custom_name,

│ on modules/my_module/main.tf line 50, in resource "aws_lambda_function" "custom_name":

│ 50: resource "aws_lambda_function" "custom_name" {

│

╵"
```

The workaround is to remove the module from terraform and start from scratch.

My code:

```
data "aws_cloudformation_stack" "custom_name" {
  name = "custom_name"
}

data "aws_caller_identity" "current" {}

resource "random_id" "id" {
  byte_length = 10
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    principals {
      type = "Service"
      identifiers = ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]
    }
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_for_lambda" {
  name = "LambdaFunction-${random_id.id.hex}"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role.json
}

resource "null_resource" "install_dependencies" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "pip install -r ${path.module}/src/requirements.txt -t ${path.module}/src/ --upgrade"
  }
  # Only re-run this if the dependencies or their versions
  # have changed since the last deployment with Terraform
  triggers = {
    dependencies_versions = filemd5("${path.module}/src/requirements.txt")
    # source_code_hash = random_uuid.lambda_src_hash.result # This is a suitable option too
  }
}

data "archive_file" "python_lambda_package" {
  type = "zip"
  source_dir = "${path.module}/src"
  output_path = "${path.module}/.${random_id.id.hex}/lambda.zip"
  depends_on = [null_resource.install_dependencies]
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "custom_name" {
  function_name = "custom_name-${random_id.id.hex}"
  filename = data.archive_file.python_lambda_package.output_path
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.python_lambda_package.output_base64sha256
  role = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn
  runtime = "python3.10"
  memory_size = 1024
  handler = "function.handler"
  timeout = 600
  tracing_config {
    mode = "Active"
  }
}
```

Try to run terraform apply and expected to be able to create the zip file

Comment: Why use this `${random_id.id.hex}`?

Comment: You should always install the dependencies, not only if they changed. The remaining code should then be smart enough not to upload them / update the lambda because the zip file has not changed. If you only build the dependencies sometimes then the rest of the code, in particular the `aws_lambda_function` function will not know what to do.